# Integral equality using lower limit of integration

Tags: integration, analysis

Let $\alpha$ be real and $f$ be a monotone increasing function. For a fixed $r_{0}\geq 0$, I am looking for an $\widetilde{r}$ such that for all $r\geq 0$, $$\int_{r_{0}}^{r}{\frac{sds}{f(s)}}-\alpha=\int_{\widetilde{r}}^{r}{\frac{sds}{f(s)}}.$$ For example when $f(s)=s^{2}$ we have the equality with $\widetilde{r}=r_{0}\exp(\alpha)$.

Can someone help in the general situation or at least show the existence of $r_{0}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rearrange $$\int_{r_0}^r \frac{sds}{f(s)}-\alpha=\int_{\tilde r}^r\frac{sds}{f(s)}$$
as
$$\alpha = \int_{r_0}^r \frac{sds}{f(s)}-\int_{\tilde r}^r\frac{sds}{f(s)}=\int_{r_0}^{\tilde r} \frac{sds}{f(s)}$$

Since the integral of any function varies continuously with its limits of integration, such an $\tilde r$ must exist provided $$\min \left\{\int_{r_0}^r \frac{sds}{f(s)}\ \middle |\  r \ge 0\right\} \le \alpha \le \max \left\{\int_{r_0}^r \frac{sds}{f(s)}\ \middle|\  r \ge 0\right\}$$

Comment: It is important that $\widetilde{r}$ does not depend on $r$. Besides that I have $\min \left\{\int_{r_0}^r \frac{sds}{f(s)}\ \middle |\  r \ge 0\right\}=-\infty$ and $\max \left\{\int_{r_0}^r \frac{sds}{f(s)}\ \middle |\  r \ge 0\right\}=\infty$, so such $\widetilde{r}$ always exists?

Comment: $\tilde r$ is determined by $$\alpha = \int_{r_0}^{\tilde r} \frac{sds}{f(s)}$$ which has no dependence on $r$. If those are your infimum and supremum, then yes, any $\alpha$ will have an $\tilde r$ that provides it. Note that depending on how fast $f(s)$ grows with respect to $s$ itself, there may be more than one solution for $\tilde r$.

Comment: ok, thank you. Do you have an idea why $\widetilde{r}$ is easy to compute in the case when $f(s)=s^{2}$?

Comment: It will generally be easy to compute when $s/f(s)$ is a form with an elementary antiderivative. Unfortunately, most integrals do not have one, so you need to use numerical integration methods - and probably a root-finder algorithm - to determine the approximate value.